# Avoiding copy-constructor / destructor when calling vector.push_back()

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, move-semantics, temporary-objects

`MemRef` is a small object that contains a pointer to memory, and a length.  It's central to an optimization project to minimize string copying in a critical section.  tokens is a `deque<MemRef>`.

As I identify tokens in an input buffer, I want to construct `MemRef`s and add them to the token deque.  First try was:

```
MemRef foo(token_begin, token_len);
tokens.push_back( foo );
```

Since I saw dtor calls here, it clued me that **foo** was being created, copied, and then destroyed.  Next try was:

```
tokens.push_back( MemRef(token_begin, token_len) );
```

But I saw the same behavior.  My guess is that a temporary is being created, copied into the deque, and then destroyed, and that perhaps this is where the subject of "move semantics" comes in (which I'm very unclear about).

Is there a way to, in effect, construct the `MemRef` directly into the tokens deque, without creating and destroying a temporary?

(I'm using Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) with --std=c++11)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/emplace_back):

```
tokens.emplace_back(token_begin, token_len);
```

This will construct a `MemRef` in-place. Note that this is only available with c++11.

Comment: Yes! It worked for me, despite not knowing whether my compiler is completely c++11 compliant yet.  I guess it's close enough, anyway.

Comment: I believe clang-500.2.79 is mostly c++11 compliant. You may need to compile with `-stdlib=libc++` in addition to `-std=c++11`

Comment: Tried with -stdlib=libc++ in addition.  No difference that I can see; still works.